# Can we enable both Embedded and Remote Sign in DocuSign API using c#?

Tags: docusignapi

Create an envelope using Server Template and then get the return URL for Embedded signing and also send the Envelope to the recipient via email to sign the document. So that , User can sign the document either using Email Link (Remote) or Embedded link in Web.  Please let me know there is any option to achieve this in DocuSign API ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A solution is to specify both a `clientUserId` and an `embeddedRecipientStartURL` when creating a Recipient.

- Specifying a `clientUserId` causes the recipient to be an "embedded" signer.
- Specifying an `embeddedRecipientStartURL` causes the recipient to also receive an official DocuSign email inviting them to sign the documents.

The `embeddedRecipientStartURL` parameter is intended to be a URL that DocuSign can redirect the signer to *within your app*, and the idea is that you take care of any necessary authentication. However, rather than supply a URL to your own app, you can instead supply a magic value of "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN". **In effect, this causes the recipient to be both embedded *and* receive an official "please sign" email from DocuSign."**

Answer (score 2):

A single recipient in an envelope workflow must be specified as EITHER a Remote recipient (so that DocuSign will send them an email when it's their turn in the routing order) OR an Embedded recipient (so that DocuSign will ***not*** send them an email) -- it's not possible to specify a recipient as both Remote and Embedded.  However, in the scenario you describe, you might consider the following approach:

- Specify the recipient as an Embedded recipient when you create the envelope.
- Immediately after creating the envelope (or when it's that recipient's turn to view/sign the envelope), your application creates and sends an email to the recipient and includes a link *to a page within your application (website)* -- you can include querystring parameters on the link URL to contain recipient name and email address.
- Develop the page in your application (the one that the email links to) such that it identifies the recipient (perhaps by reading the recipient name and email address from the querystring parameters in the URL), and then uses that information to make a "POST Recipient View" call to retrieve the URL from DocuSign that can be used to launch the recipient's signing session.

Using this approach, the recipient will still receive an email when it's their turn to sign -- but the email will be sent by your application -- and the link in the email will lead the recipient to your application where your application will then request (from DocuSign) and present (to the recipient/user) the URL to view/sign the envelope.