# Switch from embedded signing to remote signing after the envelope is sent

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to set up a certain scenario when creating a DocuSign envelope.
After creating my recipient views to proceed with embedded signing, it is possible that those signers would want to switch to remote signing.

Is there a way to switch a recipient from embedded signing to remote signing after the envelope is sent?

Should I just send a reminder notification and let the embedded signing links expire ?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one. I will look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Embedded signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning) links are for one time use only and they automatically expire after 5 minutes.

**Changing Embedded Signer to a Remote Signer**  : Update the "*clientUserId*" of the recipient to an empty value using the [updateEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/) api. This will also trigger an email to the recipient.

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

sample Json

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Also see this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543) where you can set up the recipient for Embedded and Remote signing during envelope creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this solution works if we know before the package creation that we might want the user to use the email link.
What I am trying to do is that I want, after package creation, to switch from embedded to remote and trigger an email to the signer(s)

Comment: not exactly as what I am looking for is to switch from embedded to remote after the package's creation. Hence, I would like to send an email with a DocuSign link being triggered when the user lets me know that he/she doesn't want to proceed with the embedded signing. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

While @CodingDawg provided the general solution, below is the solution in C# (as I am using the DocuSign C# SDK) in case it might help anyone in the future :

```
    if (recipients.Signers != null)
    {
        foreach (Signer signer in recipients.Signers)
        {
            signer.ClientUserId = "";
        }
    }

    // One might want to do the same for Editors, CertifiedDeliveries, etc..
   EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi();
    envelopeApi.UpdateRecipients(accountId,envelopeId,recipients);
```