# Recipient type : InPerson vs Remote

Tags: docusignapi

We are using REST API to create envelopes and the Template is set up in DocuSign, with signer roles etc. Our customer wants to be able to decide in every separate occasion whether to use InPerson signing or send the signing link via email to the recipient.

Currently/originally we implemented Embedded signing, but our customer wants the "security question" (e.g. ask for driver's license number) to be there before the signing. So that they can prove that the buyer has actually been there to sign.

Is there a way to do this? I have the DocuSign Template set up with "needs to sign" option, but when sending the request to create a new envelope, somehow change a signer to be InPerson and trigger a workflow for that?

I managed to find information about Embedded signing and clientUserId, but is there a way to deliver information for example to the Certificate of Completion, like with the InPerson case with the input showing there?

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch from In-Person (embedded) to remote signing and vice-versa, you will need to use the property **ClientUserId**. It is well described in the DocuSign article [Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign).
If you're willing to switch **after the envelope is created**, see my recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586385/switch-from-embedded-signing-to-remote-signing-after-the-envelope-is-sent) that deals with the same issue.

To implement the "security questions", DocuSign offers multiple [authentication option](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-authentication-options). It seems to me that you are looking to use the "ID Check" authentication [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-signing-id-check-authentication)
In C#, it would look like this when you try to implement ID Check for a given signer :

```
signer.RequireIdLookup = bool.TrueString;
signer.IdCheckConfigurationName = "ID Check $";
```

Lastly, for your question regarding the authentication method and the certificate of completion, the Embedded signing article I mentioned above explains well what happens for the authentication method in the certificate completion below :

*The authenticationMethod is an enumerated value that indicates the convention used to authenticate the signer. Since, with Embedding, you are telling Docusign that you are handling authentication this is your way of telling the platform how you authenticated the recipient. This information will also be included in the Certificate of Completion, a PDF that is automatically generated for every completed envelope.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Frederic.

Comment: I think we are talking about different things. What I would like, is to switch between In-Person signing AND embedded/remote.  InPerson meaning the thing you set up when configuring the template in DS, which is different from embedded. As I would like to use the feature to enable the signing host (sales rep) to be able to verify the identity of the signer (buyer). And that information would be stored to DocuSign. I'm currently not in the need of actually authenticating the person with DocuSign.