# Is it possible to use a returnUrl when sending a sign request in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am wondering whether it is possible to use a returnUrl which the user is redirected to after signing the document, but using the path where you email the sign request out to the recipients.

The embedded flow does not work for us, unless I am missing something, because the 5 minute timeout does not work.

I would like to email the sign requests out to the recipients and then after they complete their signing redirect them to a custom "thank you" page.

The issue is that you can have one sign immediately, but the other recipients take days, and by the time they get to the request it is timed out. I have also tried to recreate the RecipientViewRequest, but the new URL simply shows me the document to sign without the option to sign it, even though the watermark says "In Progress".

I am using the C# SDK, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending emails to embedded recipients, specify **clientUserId** and **embeddedRecipientStartURL** when creating the Recipient.

> **[embeddedRecipientStartURL](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters)** : This is a sender provided valid URL string for redirecting an embedded recipient. When using this option, the embedded recipient still receives an email from DocuSign, just as a remote recipient would, but when the document link in the email is clicked the recipient is redirected, through DocuSign, to this URL to complete their actions. When routing to the URL, it is up to the sender’s system (the server responding to the URL) to then request a recipient token to launch a signing session.

Here is a sample [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Please sign the agreement",
  "status": "sent",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
                "name": "jane doe",
                "recipientId": 1,
                "clientUserId":"1234",
                "embeddedRecipientStartURL":"<Add Url to your App here>",
                "tabs": {"signHereTabs": [{ "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "80"}]}
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [{ "documentId": "1", "name": "Contract", "fileExtension": "txt", "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP" }]
}
```

When the recipient clicks the link in their email, he is redirected to the url that you specify in **embeddedRecipientStartURL**. After your app authenticates and identifies the recipient, You will then have to request a recipient token using the [CreateRecipientView](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) api and specify the url for the custom thank you page in the `returnUrl` parameter. Make sure you include `https://`

```
   {
      "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
      "userName": "jane doe",
      "recipientId": 1,
      "clientUserId":"1234",
      "returnUrl":"https://www.google.com", //Include your custom thank you page here
      "AuthenticationMethod" :"email"
   }
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543)

Comment: Not quite - this is for the starting URL rather than the returnUrl

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if that helps.