# Disable In-Person Signer email notification to the host

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to know if it's possible to disable the email notification to a host when using In-Person signing. ( sent you a document to host for an in-person signing session.)

Repro:

1 - Envelope is created using API containing 3 recipients: One In-Person captive Signer and two remote signers.

2 - Host receives an email notification.

[In-Person Sign Email Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7mUu.jpg)

JSON:

```
`{
   "status":"sent",
   "emailSubject":"Contract",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "templateId":"<templateId>"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{
                  "inPersonSigners":[
                     {
                        "hostEmail":"johndoe@email.com",
                        "hostName":"John Doe",
                        "signerName":"Ringo Starr",
                        "signerEmail":"ringostarr@email.com",
                        "roleName":"Signer 1",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "clientUserId":"1000",
                        "routingOrder":"1",
                        "embeddedRecipientStartURL":"SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                        "recipientSignatureProviders":[
                           {
                              "signatureProviderName":"UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
                              "signatureProviderOptions":{
                                 "sms":"<phoneNumber>"
                              }
                           } 
                        ]
                  ],
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "name":"John Doe",
                        "email":"johndoe@email.com",
                        "emailNotification":{
                           "emailSubject":"Contract for live in person signature attached.",
                           "emailBody":"Contract for live in person signature attached.",
                           "supportedLanguage":"en"
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 2",
                        "routingOrder":"2",
                        "recipientId":"2",
                        "recipientSignatureProviders":[
                           {
                              "signatureProviderName":"UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
                              "signatureProviderOptions":{
                                 "sms":"<phoneNumber>"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Paul McCartney",
                        "email":"paulmccartney@email.com",
                        "emailNotification":{
                           "emailSubject":"Contract for live in person signature attached.",
                           "emailBody":"Contract for live in person signature attached.",
                           "supportedLanguage":"en"
                        },
                        "roleName":"Signer 3",
                        "routingOrder":"2",
                        "recipientId":"3",
                        "recipientSignatureProviders":[
                           {
                              "signatureProviderName":"UniversalSignaturePen_OpenTrust_Hash_TSP",
                              "signatureProviderOptions":{
                                 "sms":"<phoneNumber>"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "customFields":{
                  "textCustomFields":[
                     {
                        "value":"<salesforcecontractId>",
                        "required":"false",
                        "show":"false",
                        "name":"##SFContract"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "eventNotification":{
      "RecipientEvents":[
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"Completed"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"sent"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"delivered"
         },
         {
            "recipientEventStatusCode":"declined"
         }
      ],
      "EnvelopeEvents":[
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Delivered"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"completed"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"sent"
         },
         {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode":"Declined"
         }
      ]
   }
}`
```

As I'm using an URL that can be accessed from my application the email notification to the host is unnecessary.

Considerations to keep in mind:

1. None of the recipients neither the host is a DocuSign user;
2. The option "Suppress emails to embedded signers" under Signing Settings is already checked;
3. The host will not always be a recipient.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `"embeddedRecipientStartURL":"SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN"` from the inPerson recipient definition.

Specifying an `embeddedRecipientStartURL` causes the recipient to also receive an official DocuSign email inviting them to sign the documents. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543) for more information.

From Official [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters)

> **embeddedRecipientStartURL** is a sender provided valid URL string for redirecting an embedded recipient. When using this option, the embedded recipient still receives an email from DocuSign, just as a remote recipient would, but when the document link in the email is clicked the recipient is redirected, through DocuSign, to this URL to complete their actions. When routing to the URL, it is up to the sender's system (the server responding to the URL) to then request a recipient token to launch a signing session.

Comment: Hi @praveen-reddy, do you know if your answer is still valid? The ~ same payload is triggering a mail from the impersonated user (that we use to interact with the API) to the signing session's host. The only difference is  `"inPersonSigners": [{"inPersonSigningType": "inPersonSigner", ...}]` and no `clientUserId` (which is for "embed" and not "in person", right?).