# Email notification to user is not sent when ClientUserId is provided

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create envelope from template i uploaded to my account.
Using following code to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ApiException {
    // Enter your DocuSign credentials
    String UserName = "my-user-name";
    String Password = "my-password";
    String IntegratorKey = "my-integrator-key";

    // for production environment update to "www.docusign.net/restapi"
    String BaseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

    // initialize the api client for the desired environment
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    apiClient.setBasePath(BaseUrl);

    // create JSON formatted auth header
    String creds = "{\"Username\":\"" + UserName + "\",\"Password\":\"" + Password + "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
    apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", creds);

    // assign api client to the Configuration object
    Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);

    //////////////////////////////// LOGIN START
    // login call available off the AuthenticationApi
    AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();

    // login has some optional parameters we can set
    AuthenticationApi.LoginOptions loginOps = authApi.new LoginOptions();
    loginOps.setApiPassword("true");
    loginOps.setIncludeAccountIdGuid("true");
    LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.login(loginOps);

    // note that a given user may be a member of multiple accounts
    List<LoginAccount> loginAccounts = loginInfo.getLoginAccounts();

    System.out.println("LoginInformation: " + loginAccounts);
    // use the |accountId| we retrieved through the Login API to create the Envelope
    String accountId = loginAccounts.get(0).getAccountId();
    /////////////////////////////////////// LOGIN END

    ////////////////////////////////////// CREATE ENVELOPE START
    // create a new envelope object that we will manage the signature request through
    EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envDef.setEmailSubject("Hey! Sign the following document");

    // assign template information including ID and role(s)
    envDef.setTemplateId("ebbe20e3-1c2e-4696-a0c4-41269bf54aeb");

    // create a template role with a valid templateId and roleName and assign signer info
    TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
    tRole.setRoleName("Client");
    String name = "Jake";
    String email = "someEmail@goes.here";
    tRole.setName(name);
    tRole.setEmail(email);
    tRole.setClientUserId("someClientUuid");

    // create a list of template roles and add our newly created role
    List<TemplateRole> templateRolesList = new ArrayList<>();
    templateRolesList.add(tRole);

    Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
    Text clientIdField = new Text();
    clientIdField.setTabLabel("CustomerId");
    clientIdField.setValue("I changed text from API! It works!");
    List<Text> textList = new ArrayList<>();
    textList.add(clientIdField);
    tabs.setTextTabs(textList);
    tRole.setTabs(tabs);

    // assign template role(s) to the envelope
    envDef.setTemplateRoles(templateRolesList);

    // send the envelope by setting |status| to "sent". To save as a draft set to "created"
    envDef.setStatus("sent");

    // use the |accountId| we retrieved through the Login API to create the Envelope

    // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

    // call the createEnvelope() API
    EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

    System.out.println("EnvelopeSummary: " + envelopeSummary);
    ///////////////////////////////////// CREATE ENVELOPE END

    String envelopeId = envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId();

    //////////////////////////////////////// CREATE RECIPIENT VIEW
    // use the |accountId| we retrieved through the Login API
    // instantiate a new EnvelopesApi object
    // set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
    RecipientViewRequest returnUrl = new RecipientViewRequest();
    returnUrl.setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com/devcenter");
    returnUrl.setAuthenticationMethod("email");

    // recipient information must match embedded recipient info we provided in step #2
    returnUrl.setEmail(email);
    returnUrl.setUserName(name);
    returnUrl.setClientUserId("someClientUuid");

    // call the CreateRecipientView API then navigate to the URL to start the signing session
    ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, returnUrl);

    System.out.println("ViewUrl: " + recipientView);
    //////////////////////////////////////// CREATE RECIPIENT VIEW
}
```

And i noticed strange thing - when i provide clientUserId field to my TemplateRole, while creating envelope from template - email notification to sign document is not sent to user. But when i remove this field - email is sent successfully. 
The problem is that i need that clientUserId in my TemplateRole to be able to properly generate ViewUrl to use in my application.

So is it a bug or a feature, that notification is not sent with provided clientUserId in TemplateRole? Did not found any documentation about that on official site.

Comment: Also tried to specify RecipientEmailNotification in my TemplateRole - does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `clientUserId` is specified the recipient is considered as an [embedded recipient](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign). By default only remote recipients receive email notifications.

If you want embedded recipients to receive email notifications then set the `embeddedRecipientStartURL` property.

```
tRole.setEmbeddedRecipientStartURL("SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN")
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543) for more information

Official [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters)