# Signers getting email Embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am using embedded signing through docusign and passing template ID to envelope

{

```
        TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
        tRole.Email = recipientEmail;
        tRole.Name = recipientName;
        tRole.RoleName = "Test";

        tRole.ClientUserId = "1234";



        tRole.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

        List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };


        envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;


        envDef.TemplateId = "ba77b95b-1806-4345-99ab-fa19e769ff46
```

}
and creating recipient view as below

```
        RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()

        {

            ReturnUrl = "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",

            ClientUserId = "1234", 

            AuthenticationMethod = "email",

            UserName = recipientName,

            Email = recipientEmail

        };
```

I am generating a URl and asking the signer to sign from my app. But the document is not getting completed and an email is sent to signer containing link to sign the document. As per docusign if we include client user ID the email is not sent but still the signer is getting email.

If i do the same using production account I am not facing this issue and the document is completed once the signer signs from my app. This issue is only occurring with sandbox developer account credentials. I don't know how to fix since i can test only on sandbox account

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign will not send emails containing the signing link for embedded signers.

Can you please provide the envelopeId where you think the signing email was sent to the embedded signer.

There are special cases where an embedded signer can also be a remote signer. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543). Based on the information you have provided this does not seem to be the case.