# DocuSign API embedded signing with email notification when envelope is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I have a rails app that uses docusign_rest gem. I can get the URL for embedded signing when the envelope is created but an email notification is not sent to the signer. I have played with these settings but cannot find the right settings for what I wanted.

[Envelope Delivery Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CByMc.png)

Comment: Can you please share what endpoint you are using for embedded signing? If you are using recipientview (by putting clientuserid in envelope) then DocuSign does not send notification to signer for the embedded signing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we enable both Embedded and Remote Sign in DocuSign API using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303672/can-we-enable-both-embedded-and-remote-sign-in-docusign-api-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify the `embeddedRecipientStartURL` in your request. This will ensure the embedded signer receives a notification to sign the document.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28815901/1219543)