# DocuSign - Embedded Recipient that is also a DocuSign User needs to view Envelope in their Inbox

Tags: integration, digital-signature, docusignapi

I have a web application wherein our users create contracts and we have integrated with DocuSign through an embedded recipient experience.

My web application is fairly involved in gathering the appropriate signers, sending emails, requesting signatures, keeping up with signer statuses, etc., and so I believe that an embedded recipient experience makes the most sense for us.

However, our first client using the integration has already been using DocuSign for some time and their signers (CEOs, CFOs and the like) are accustomed to logging into DocuSign, seeing envelopes in their inbox and clicking on them to sign - which is only possible in an integration by adding them as remote recipients. Embedded recipients cannot be associated to a DocuSign user account.

I'd like to keep using embedded recipients, but my client desperately wants to see envelopes created from my application in their DocuSign user account inbox and sign them from there without first having to log into my application.

Is there any clever way to deliver such a request with an embedded recipient experience? Even an atypical workaround, like sharing documents between the embedded recipient and the user account or some other recipient type of which I'm not aware, etc.?

Comment: Do they want to sign it or only want a copy in their email? If they want to receive a copy of an envelope in an email then you can add them as a CC recipient in your envelope, once all recipients will sign they will get an envelope copy in their email box. RestApi reference - https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/carbonCopy

Comment: Amit, thanks for replying. The user will want to sign the envelope in my use case.

Comment: You can add same user twice in the envelope, first as embedded signer then CC recipient at the end of routing order in the envelope. So as a embedded recipient user will first sign that envelope then same user is present as CC recipient later in the the routing order which will help in seeing envelope in user's inbox. Will this work for you?

Comment: Would adding the embedded signer as a CC recipient allow the user to log into their DocuSign account, see the envelope in their inbox, and sign the envelope from there?

Or would the user always have to access the envelope through the returnUrl defined at the time of the envelope being sent in order to be recognized as the embedded signer?

Currently the only way to access the returnUrl is by logging into our application.

Comment: You need to add user as both first as Embedded Signer lets say as routing order 1, then user has to use your App to Sign the envelope. Then add same user also as a CC Recipient later in the routing order lets say Routing Order 2 or more after all signing recipients. Once all recipients have completed signing ceremony then automatically an envelope will go to CC recipient's Email/DocuSign account.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you, Amit. Unfortunately that solution won't satisfy my client's use case. I appreciate your fast responses though!

Comment: There is another way to start the signing ceremony for embedded recipient which is shared at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059117/3530898  In this case, signer will receive an email and on clicking button in an email we will direct the user to your App, but in this case as well they will not be able to see the envelope in their DocuSign Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. When creating an embedded signing session the recipient becomes what's referred to as a Captive Recipient. Captive Recipients follow a different set of rules in regards to email notifications and presence in an inbox.

For example, Captive Recipients don't receive email notifications by default -- but they can supply an email to be CC'ed onto the envelope.

Since the Captive Recipient also has a universal account number, the user is technically part of an account outside of yours or your recipients.

IE: Your recipient views his inbox linked to his userId on account XXXXXXXXX.
The Captive Recipient is part of account YYYYYYYYYY with its own unique userId, so there's nothing for it to match up to.

If your app relies on embedded signing to load DocuSign envelopes into something like an iFrame, you can still do that without using an embedded recipient, which would give you the ability to load them through your webApp as well as let your signer access them via his DocuSign inbox.

To retrieve the signing URL, you make a POST call to `https://{endpoint}.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient` with the following call body:

```
{
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost/returnUrl",
  "authenticationMethod":"email",
  "email": "{recipientEmail}",
  "userName": "{recipientFullName}",
  "recipientId":"{recipientId}"
}
```