# Docuisgn Embedded signing plus email

Tags: docusignapi

We have a requirement that we want to send DocuSign email to recipient who is marked as Captive /embedded. By default DocuSign will not send email to embedded signers. In case the recipient doesn't want to sign at our web site, they can open envelope later from their email. Is there some setting like that or some setting in Rest API call?

Answer (score 1):

Found Answer at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303672/can-we-enable-both-embedded-and-remote-sign-in-docusign-api-using-c/28815901#28815901).
If sender sets embeddedRecipientStartURL to SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN for particular recipient, the recipient is directed to an embedded signing or viewing process directly hosted at DocuSign.

**In effect, this causes the recipient to be both embedded and receive an official "please sign" email from DocuSign.**

Sample Json

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "tabs": {
                        "fullNameTabs": [{
                            "fontColor": "white",
                            "pageNumber": 1,
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "xPosition": 400,
                            "yPosition": 15
                        }]
                    },
                    "name": "Full Name",
                    "email": "signersemail@email.com",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "clientUserId": "1000",
                    "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN"
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "1"
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<Base64Bytes>",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Doc.pdf"
        }
    }],
    "status": "sent",
    "emailBlurb": "Test Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Subject"
}
```

Comment: sure, you can do that, but the email is received right away, not after someone went to the app first and decided to wish to receive an email instead (Which is what I understood the requirements are)

Comment: @Ibrar Thanks, Yes we needed email instantly.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, depending on the exact use-case.
It seems that you want to first do embedded signing (which I assume you know how to do) and then if the user select something in your app - you want to send an email for the same exact recipient to sign the same exact envelope. So you have to make an additional API call at that point to update the recipient to remote and re-send the envelope.
That can be done using a [PUT call to update the envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update/). You have to add `?resend_envelope=true` to that call

Comment: Thanks Inbrar . We are looking for something that is done automatically from DocuSign. Update Call would be manual process or we need to create some service or job for that. that is not feasible at this moment.